# Android: dynamically distributed LinearLayout content?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I've tried everything there is to try and I'm beginning to suspect this is not really possible.

What I'm looking for is dynamic distribution of N children in a (horizontal) LinearLayout based on their widths. Kind of like a HTML table does it, by dynamically calculating the column widths. Basically I want to turn my ListView into a table with dynamically calculated widths, as such:

```
<table class="ListView">
  <tr class="LinearLayout"><td class="TextView">John:</td><td class="TextView">123-456-789</td></tr>
  <tr class="LinearLayout"><td class="TextView">Mike:</td><td class="TextView">321-654-987</td></tr>
  <tr class="LinearLayout"><td class="TextView">Sally:</td><td class="TextView">789-456-123</td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I do something like that in Android? Remember, I don't just want to split it into two equally long parts. I need the content to determine the column width *and* fill the entire LinearLayout. Like this (assuming there are only two child elements):

```
[ [--TextView--] [--------TextView--------] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using `LinearLayout`. You must use a `TableLayout` with all elements in the `TableRow' having width`wrap_content`. If your no of rows to be displayed is dynamic, then you have to create and insert rows in the ViewGroup dynamically, otherwise its pretty straight forward for static data.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `android:layout_weight="1"` for all of your `TextView` in `TableRow`, but using too much **weight** is bad for performance.

Comment: That's not going to work. It divides the LinearLayout into *equal* portions. The widths will not be determined by content. It's the same as setting "table-layout:fixed;" to a HTML table in CSS when it should really be "table-layout:auto;".

Comment: ah i forgot something, did you set the width to `wrap_content` instead of `0dp`?

Comment: If I do that, then the elements won't fill up all the space in LinearLayout.

Comment: it will fill, if you set `layout_weight` to 1.

Comment: You might be onto something. I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This will take up much more space"
            android:layout_weight="20" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_weight="80" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: What it would look like.]

NOTE: The background of "This will take up much more space" is gray, because I took the screenshot while mousing over that TextView in order for the full length of it to be visible.

Comment: You've manually set the weight ratio (20:80). If the second TextView contains a longer string it will not be resized.

Comment: I'm thinking you MIGHT be able to change the weight dynamically through Java, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.